# Need help recreating jquery effect

Tags: jquery

Need help replicating specific effect found on a site (link is below). The best I can describe is;

I have 18 different images, which once clicked should slide down a box display different images. The only site I've seen so far is the one listed below. If anyone can help, that would be awesome. Or if anyone could please direct me to a plugin that would be great as well. Thank you!

Link: http://giangnguyendesign.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you want to replicate it, just go through the source of the site. HTML and JS are not compiled, so you should be able to see how it was exactly achieved.

But if you are just simply want to have a slide down effect, jquery has one already built-in, ie.

```
$("div").slideDown();
```

http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: I would but, not good at all in jQuery...that's why I was looking for a plugin. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, the plugins in use can be seen by just doing an inspect, and jquery is pretty much what the sample site you provided used in company with some own scripting. Take a look at http://giangnguyendesign.com/wp-content/themes/giangnguyen/js/giangnguyen-main.js to see how it uses it.

Comment: Looking at that it only seems to deal with the hover over the header to reveal a "hello message" and upon entering the content area it slides up to close it. What I'm after is actually the effect when you click on one of his works. The slide that takes once you click on a image.

Answer (score 1):

The site is using the vgrid plugin

http://blog.xlune.com/2009/09/vgrid/

http://jquerystyle.com/2010/03/25/vgrid